# Multiple conditional modify variable in elixir

Tags: elixir

How do I write this Ruby code with Elixir?

```rb
value = 0
value += 3 if cond1
value += 2 if cond2
value += 8 if cond3
value -= 3 if cond4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val = 0
val = if cond1, do: val + 3, else: val
val = if cond2, do: val + 2, else: val
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create a helper function if you want to use piping.

```rb
def add_if(total, condition, value) do
  if condition, do: total + value, else: total
end


value =
  0
  |> add_if(cond1, 3)
  |> add_if(cond2, 2)
  |> add_if(cond3, 8)
  |> add_if(cond4, -3)
```

Depending on what you're doing, it can also make sense to have the conditions/logic in whatever function is modifying your data. So your pipeline could look something like this:

```rb
0
|> maybe_add_three("little pigs")
|> increment_by_two()
|> sum_with([4, 3, 1])
|> go_back_three_spaces(true)
```